# Change root path for Spark Web UI?

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, jupyter

I'm working to setup Jupyter notebook servers on Kubernetes that are able to launch `pyspark`. Each user is able to have a multiple servers running at once, and would access each by navigating to the appropriate host combined with a path to the server's fully-qualified name. For example: `http://<hostname>/<username>/<notebook server name>`.

I have a top-level function defined that allows a user create a `SparkSession` that points to the Kubernetes master URL and sets their pod to be the Spark driver.

This is all well and good, but I would like to enable end users to access the URL for the Spark Web UI so that they can track their jobs. The [Spark on Kubernetes documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#accessing-driver-ui) has port forwarding as their recommended scheme for achieving this. It seems to be that for any security-minded organization, allowing any random user to setup port forwarding in this way would be unacceptable.

I would like to use an `Ingress` Kubernetes definition to allow external access to the driver's Spark Web UI. I've setup something like the following:

```
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: <notebook namespae>
  name: <username>-<notebook server name>-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  selector:
    app: <username>-<notebook server name>-notebook
  ports:
  - name: app-svc-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8888
    targetPort: 8888
  - name: spark-ui-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 4040
    targetPort: 4040

# Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: workspace
  name: <username>-<notebook server name>-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <hostname>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /<username>/<notebook server name>
        backend:
          serviceName: <username>-<notebook server name>-svc
          servicePort: app-svc-port
      - path: /<username>/<notebook server name>/spark-ui
        backend:
          serviceName: <username>-<notebook server name>-svc
          servicePort: spark-ui-port
```

However, under this setup, when I navigate to `http://<hostname>/<username>/<notebook server name>/spark-ui/`, I'm redirected to `http://<hostname>/jobs`. This is because `/jobs` is the default entry point to Spark's Web UI. However, I don't have an ingress rule for that path, and can't set such a rule since every user's Web UI would collide with each other in the load balancer (unless I have a  misunderstanding, which is totally possible).

Under the [Spark UI configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui) settings, there doesn't seem to be a way to set a root path for the Spark session. You can change the port on which it runs, but what I'd like to do make the UI serve at something like: `http://<hostname>/<username>/<notebook server name>/spark-ui/<jobs, stages, etc>`. Is there really no way of changing what comes after the hostname of the URL and before the last part?

Answer (score 4):

1: set your spark config

```
spark.ui.proxyBase: /foo
```

2: Set the nginx annotations in Ingress

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: http://$host/
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: http://$host/foo/
```

3:Annotation to rewrite target:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

spec:
  rules:
  - host: <host>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: <service>
          servicePort: <port>
        path: /foo(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how this can be used with spark-on-k8s-operator ?

Comment: Would you have an equivalent configuration with Traefik ingress controller? (as asked in the original question)

Comment: @PascalGILLET did you manage to get this fixed using Traefik?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this. Specifically you can do this by setting the spark.ui.proxyBase property within spark-defaults.conf or at the run-time.

Example:

echo "spark.ui.proxyBase                 $SPARK_UI_PROXYBASE" >> /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf;

Then this should work.